# Issue initialising one variable of type dictionary with another variabjle of type dict

Tags: vba, vbscript, qtp

```
Dim globalDict
Dim localDict
.
'Data from a excel is loaded to globalDict

Set localDict=globalDict(1)

localDict(item1)="AAA"
```

This update updates the value in `globalDict` as well. Its as if `localDict` is just a pointer.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by design: see [Set Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44(v=vs.84).aspx)  under [Statements (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw9cadb(v=vs.84).aspx):

> Generally, when you use `Set` to assign an object reference to a
>   variable, **no copy of the object** is created for that variable.
>   Instead, **a reference to the object** is created. More than one
>   object variable can refer to the same object. Because these variables
>   are references to (rather than copies of) the object, any change in
>   the object is reflected in all variables that refer to it.

You could make an identical copy of a *Dictionary* object as follows:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName

Dim globalDict
Set globalDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
globalDict.Add "a", "Athens"    ' add some keys and items
globalDict.Add "b", "Belgrade"
globalDict.Add "c", "Cairo"

    ' create an identical copy of a Dictionary object
Dim localDict, arrKeys, arrItems, ii          ' declare variables
Set localDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arrKeys   = globalDict.Keys               ' get the keys
   'arrItems  = globalDict.Items              ' get the items: unnecessary
For ii= 0 To UBound( arrKeys)
   '(debug output) strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & arrKeys(ii) & vbTab & arrItems(ii)
   localDict.Add arrKeys(ii), globalDict( arrKeys(ii)) ' add appropriate keys and items
Next
    '           identical copy is created now

localDict("b") = "Brno"

strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & globalDict("b")
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine &  localDict("b")
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "-"
'strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & 

Wscript.Echo strResult ' the only `Echo` => run under `CScript.exe` or `WScript.exe`
```

**Output**:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\37644677.vbs
37644677.vbs
Belgrade
Brno
-
```

Comment: Thanks Jose, do you know how I could copy the content alone?